# Obtener valor de radio button y guardar en variable php en tiempo real

Tags: javascript, radiobutton

estoy mostrando unos valores y los valores de compra cambian según mis radio button

[image: Dependiendo la elección de estos valores deben cambiar los valores de compra]

Y estos son los valores de compra
Ya funciona cuando cambio de tipo de envio se muestre el precio que es

[image: Ya funciona cuando cambio de tipo de envio se muestre el precio que es]

y pasar hacer mis operaciones estoy haciendo esta operacion en el BLADE

```
@php                        
  $seguro=2;                
  $envio="";
  $totalseguro=($seguro*$totalPrice)/100;
  $total=$totalPrice+$envio+$totalseguro;
@endphp
```

Ahora solo lo que necesito es pasar el VALUE de mis radio buttons a la variable $envio y que cada que los cambie, se cambie también el total en mi vista, pero no logro conseguirlo.

Estos son mis radio button

```
<input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="shipping_type" id="estandar" value="25" checked>
<input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="shipping_type" id="express"value="45">
```

Alguna idea?

Gracias :D

Comment: Y cuál es el problema de manejarlo con javascript? Simplemente detectas los eventos click de los radio button, obtienes su valor y luego, con un selector asignar el valor y hacer los cálculos con javascript: $(".envio").val(envio); $(".total").val(total), etc.

Comment: Justo eso es lo que necesito, pero no se mucho de JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Básicamente debes agregarle un id a los elementos que se verán afectados por el cálculo:

```
Costo envío: <p id="envio"></p>
Monto: <p id="monto"></p>
Total: <p id="total"></p>
```

Ahora que ya tienen un identificador y podrás acceder a ellos, sólo debes preocuparte por capturar los eventos en los radio buttons.

```
<input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="shipping_type" id="estandar" value="25" checked>
<input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="shipping_type" id="express"value="45">
```

Debes agregar un [EventListener](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_addeventlistener.asp) a tus elementos:

```
<script>
  document.querySelectorAll('input[name="shipping_type"]').forEach((elem) => {
    elem.addEventListener("change", function(event) {
      var montoEnvio = event.target.value;
      
      // Obtienes los valores para recalcular el total:
      var monto = document.getElementById('monto').textContent;
      var total = parseFloat(montoEnvio) + parseFloat(monto);

      // Colocas el nuevo total en el elemento
      document.getElementById('total').textContent = total;
    });
  });
</script>
```

Con querySelectorAll obtenemos todos los elementos especificados por el selector, en este caso por inputs con nombre "shipping_type", luego con un **forEach** recorremos todos y agregamos el **EventListener** `change`, cada vez que cambia obtenemos el valor que será el monto de envío, finalmente hacemos los cálculos.

Este proceso sería más sencillo si utilizaras **JQuery**.

Comment: Excelente, muchisimas gracias, me sirivio de mucho